# Creating Heat-Map in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, heat-map, references

Is there any tutorial about creating a heat-map in ArcMap 10.1?

Comment: It's not a step-by-step tutorial but the steps have been outlined at [**Ask A Cartographer**](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=319).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use the [Point Density](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000000v000000) and [Kernel Density](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Kernel_Density/009z0000000s000000/) GP tools that calculates a magnitude per unit area from point or point/polyline feature, respectively, sand see if the results is something that you could accept to be a heatmap.

Comment: what type of data I need to use for "Input point features"? I am using .shp and csv files but I am getting this message:  "one or more dropped items were invalid and will note be added to the control"